# Mockito spy return mock object with org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue

Tags: java, mockito, spy

I am trying to test the following code using Mockito:

```
class Item {
    String name;
    int age;
    String getInfo() {
        return name + age.toString();
    }
}

class Article {
    Item item = new Item();
    Article() {
    }

    void calculate() {
        item = prepareItem();
        String info = item.getInfo();
        println("The info is " + info);

    }

    Item prepareItem() {
        item.name = "item";
        return item;
}
```

I am trying to test the method `calculate()`, this is testcase:

```
    @Test
    public void testCalculate() {

        @Mock Item item;
        Article article = new Article();
        Article articleSpy = Mockito.spy(article);

        Mockito.doReturn(item).when(articleSpy).prepareItem();
        article.calculate();
    }
```

Then I got the following info:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
    Item$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$4ffb1868 cannot be returned by getMetaClass()
    getMetaClass() should return MetaClass
```

Can spy return a mock object? What is the reason of this error? And how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if that's the only problem, but you should be calling `doReturn(item).when(articleSpy).prepareItem()` instead of `doReturn().when(articleSpy).prepareItem(item)`

Comment: yes, it should be the way you mentioned, but still the same

Comment: I also never saw mock initialized inside method with annotation. What version of mockito are you using? When I write `Item item = mock(Item.class)` instead of `@Mock Item item`, your code runs fine.

Comment: I used Item item = mock(Item.class), it is the same

Comment: There must be something else you're not showing. After making these two changes, the code and test is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Mock` is not applicable for a local variable. Why do you need the mock anyway? I think you dont need the item to be mocked. Just create a test object `Item` to your needs. Mocks are rather to prevent real methods from being called.

Try this instead:

```
@Test
public void testCalculate() {
    Item item = new Item();

    Article article = new Article();
    Article articleSpy = Mockito.spy(article);

    Mockito.doReturn(item).when(articleSpy).prepareItem();
    article.calculate();
}
```

If you really need the spy to return a Mock, `Item item = Mockito.mock(Item.class);` should work in Mocktio 1.10. I would not suggest you to do this, because in most cases it is not needed. Most of the time you can simplify your code (=> test-driven development).

If you absolutely need it, this would be a working example:

```
Item item = Mockito.mock(Item.class);
Mockito.when(item.getInfo()).thenReturn("bla bla");

Article article = Mockito.spy(Article.class);
Mockito.doReturn(item).when(article).prepareItem();
article.calculate();
```

Comment: Shouldnt `Article article = Mockito.spy(new Article());` be enough? No need for 2 variables

Comment: How about we want to use the method from Item class in the calcuate() method, I update the code